# Building a Flutter FAB

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a floating Action Button that expend. When the button expended I want to be able to tap or press on the icons that inside the expended FAB. I am using flutter. i am trying to add navigation to the icons. I have tried to put in the basic navigation but it seems like I am not using the create code. Please Advise

```
_buildOption(Icons.perm_phone_msg, 0.0),
```

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox(
      width: expandedSize,
      height: expandedSize,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return new Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              _buildExpandedBackground(),
              _buildOption(Icons.perm_phone_msg, 0.0),
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Lover_Page())),
              _buildOption(Icons.calendar_today, -math.pi / 3),
              _buildOption(Icons.assignment_ind, -2 * math.pi / 3),
              _buildOption(Icons.video_call, math.pi),
              _buildOption(Icons.person_add, math.pi / 3),
              _buildOption(Icons.add_a_photo, 2 * math.pi / 3),
              _buildFabCore(),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Do not use comments to clarify or for code. Code is unreadable in comments. Not all comments may or may not be shown initially or in order.

Comment: I've moved comments to the question, but please edit further to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just add below statement in your **onTap()** or **onPressed()** method to navigate to next screen.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Your_Next_Screen()),
);
```

Also, refer [Navigation-Basics](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

If you use widget which doesn't have any onTap() or onPressed() method. Wrap it with **GestureDetector** or **Inkwell** widget. As both widgets have default **onTap()** method which you can use for detecting tap events.